# Is this color scheme and content layout appropriate for a powerpoint background?

Tags: background, critique, microsoft-powerpoint

I am preparing my thesis defense presentation. My work relates to the study of DNA, primarily, so I made up a relatively simple render using Blender to serve as a background theme for the PowerPoint presentation.

I am generally happy with the minimalist nature of the background, but I'm torn on two things:

First, it seems a bit blue-heavy and monochromatic. 
**What changes to the color scheme would you suggest?**

Pretty much any aspect can be changed without too much effort at this point, since everything is already set up in Blender.

Second, I am torn on whether this level of content (the single DNA molecule) is too sparse, and whether having a single element on one side makes it too unbalanced. Would you suggest any other objects in the background, or **would making it busier detract from the content?**

[image]

**EDIT**: based on feedback from the first answer, an update to the theme with another DNA molecule to balance things out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with monochromatic design. I don't think that's really an issue. Do what you feel works best.

As for balance.. it's a tad difficult to say without everything in place. But based purely on that image, yes it is terribly unbalanced. The DNA strip *yanks* the eye to it making the lower left corner feel like it's floating. Adding something tot eh lower left corner would balance things more overall.

Comment: I have edited with another test image, is that along the lines of what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the blue-white background you are using will be almost white once projected, I will suggest to make it pure white or an other color (solid gray for example).

Other thing is that if you are using gradients you had to make it more visible (a little more contrast) because of the small gamut projector have, almost all subtle gradients turn unefective.

For the composition you are asking I can suggest using DNA element on the bottom, that way you will have equivalent weights on both sides, and you can use an other DNA representation concept, lets say a DNA test pettern for example:

[image]

Comment: Good point about the gradient not projecting well, I will have to carefully test that. The gel representation you suggest wouldn't be appropriate for reasons that aren't important to the question, but an alternate representation is a good idea. I will have to think about that further.